# Alguns factos mensais

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, comunidade

Acabei de reparar que também no recente stack overflow em Espanhol, eles [publicam algumas curiosidades](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/14/el-estado-de-stack-overflow-en-espanol-febrero-2017/?cb=1) acerca do estado/perguntas/respostas do site mensalmente, não seria interessante fazer isso também no Português? (que eu saiba pelo menos nunca reparei que houvesse)

Comment: Teve uma vez até hoje, se eu não me engano.

Comment: gostei muito da ideia

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/04/estado-da-pilha-internacional-outubro-2016

Comment: 2 vezes até hoje https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/international/portugues/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não é a mesma coisa, mas o Gabe também postou [este daqui](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/06/04/stack-overflow-in-portuguese-now-with-less-beta/)

Comment: Peço desculpa pessoal, distração minha, não vi que já se tinha feito uma coisa semelhante (apesar de não ser bem o mesmo, não é por sistema)

Comment: @Miguel Não sei se entendi bem, mas me parece a mesma postagem (tirando a parte dos usuários, mas acho que isso não agregaria valor para o SOpt hoje). Todavia, acho que seria bem interessante ter essa estatística mensal mesmo. Na pior das hipóteses, nós mesmo podemos fazer com o data.SE :p

Comment: @Randrade isso é muito bem pensado